# How to Use a button that is in a layout other than your current View?

Tags: java, android-layout, android-activity

I have two layout files which I use to populate a ListActivity, 
this is the main layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/pack_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

It is a simple textView and my other layout is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/done"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Done" />
```

Which is just a button I use for my header. My adapter inflates the first layout. 
 ,how do I access my button in the other layout and implement the setonClickListener

so I added the inflator now I have:

```
LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getApplicationContext().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View r = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.button,null,false);




done = (Button)findViewById(R.id.done);`

done.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    

}
        });
```

when Im clicking the button nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

If it is part of an XML resource you could use an [Inflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html), however as stated in the documentation; it can be an expensive call. If it was me I would dynamically add views to your content view using java.